# How to create extended if-then-else statement with buttons and strings

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create an activity where there are nine buttons of different colors. I want the buttons to randomly change the textstring displayed above them only when they are pressed along with their corresponding color textstring. However, when I run the app, only the green button changes the textstring and it changes it even when the textstring displays a color besides green. Am I doing something wrong in my if-then-else code? (I have not completed the code for the remaining six color buttons.) Many thanks!!!

package com.example.franco.sampleapp;

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.Random;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final Random r_generator = new Random();
    String textViewString;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.color_text);

        Button green= (Button) findViewById(R.id.green_button);
        green.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button blue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blue_button);
        blue.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button red = (Button) findViewById(R.id.red_button);
        red.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button yellow= (Button) findViewById(R.id.yellow_button);
        yellow.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button white = (Button) findViewById(R.id.white_button);
        white.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button orange = (Button) findViewById(R.id.orange_button);
        orange.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button brown= (Button) findViewById(R.id.brown_button);
        brown.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button pink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pink_button);
        pink.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button purple = (Button) findViewById(R.id.purple_button);
        purple.setOnClickListener(this);
        textViewString = tv.getText().toString();

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == R.id.green_button && textViewString.equals("Green")) {

            Resources res = getResources();
            String[] myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.colorArray);
            String q = myString[r_generator.nextInt(myString.length)];
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.color_text);
            tv.setText(q);

        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.blue_button && textViewString.equals("Blue")) {

            Resources res = getResources();
            String[] myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.colorArray);
            String q = myString[r_generator.nextInt(myString.length)];
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.color_text);
            tv.setText(q);

        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.red_button && textViewString.equals("Red")){

            Resources res = getResources();
            String[] myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.colorArray);
            String q = myString[r_generator.nextInt(myString.length)];
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.color_text);
            tv.setText(q);

        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: Why not using a  `switch ... case`, instead?

Answer (score 1):

Don't make your `MainActivity` an `OnClickListener`.

Instead, create anonymous `OnClickListener`s to add to each button:

```
Button green= (Button) findViewById(R.id.green_button);
green.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override public void onClick(View v) {
    if (!textViewString.equals("Green")) return;
    Resources res = getResources();
    String[] myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.colorArray);
    String q = myString[r_generator.nextInt(myString.length)];
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.color_text);
    tv.setText(q);
  }
});

Button blue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blue_button);
blue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override public void onClick(View v) {
    if (!textViewString.equals("Blue")) return;
    Resources res = getResources();
    String[] myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.colorArray);
    String q = myString[r_generator.nextInt(myString.length)];
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.color_text);
    tv.setText(q);
  }
});
```

etc.

Then there is no need for a long if/else chain.

Comment: Thanks so much! However... Whenever I press a button, the app crashes. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: Look in your logcat.

Comment: `07-23 17:35:23.234 25708-25708/com.example.franco.sampleapp   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException`. I don't know what this means... Thanks!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it